# Stirling's approximation of a Laplace transform

Tags: approximation, laplace-transform

I have got the Laplace transform as follows:

$$L_X(s) = \exp(-s)\sum_{t = 0}^{\infty} \frac{s^t}{t!}\exp(-Ct^{2/\alpha}),$$
where $C$ and $\alpha$ are positive constants.

I want to prove that, using Stirling's approximation, we have

$$-\log(L_X(s)) \sim Cs^{2/\alpha}$$ as $s \to \infty$.

Comment: OK..... Sounds great. Good luck with that. So where's the question? Where's the work? What part of it are you struggling with?

Comment: Thanks. I tried using Stirling's approximation for $t!$ and then simplifying the expression for $s \to \infty$. But, I could not reach the answer I want to prove.

Comment: alrighty, good to know. I'll try a stab at the problem later if I can get some free time with my computer.

Comment: Thanks. I faced this question when I was trying to understand the exponential Tauberian theorem and apply it in a problem. I am working with the following form of the Tauberian theorem:

$\mathbb{E}(e^{-sX}) \sim e^{rs^{\alpha}}$ for $s \to \infty$ is equivalent to $\mathbb{P}(X \leq \epsilon) \sim e^{t/\epsilon^{\beta}}$ for $\epsilon \to 0$ (for $1/\alpha = 1/\beta +1$).

Comment: I'm not convinced your asymptotic expression is correct, hence a proof is impossible: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mmu64apzo3

Comment: In the case $C=\alpha=1$, for example, I think the correct asymptotic for the negative log would simply be $s$